# Show website from symfony with symfony PHP built-in web server on a smartphone

Tags: php, symfony, smartphone

I can test my programed website via the php web server that comes with symfony in any webbrowser. But i want to know if my project gets displayed correctly on a smartphone (no i won't use the built in show on mobile in chrome).

Do you guys and girls have any ideas on how to accomplish this ?

Comment: If your phone and desktop are in the same network (e.g. phone is connected via wlan) and your symfony applications runs with localhost:8000, then find out the IP of your desktop and try to open 192.168.178.20:8000 in mobile browser if 192.168.178.20 is the IP of your desktop.

Comment: @AlexanderKeil, i already tried this and found an answer to fix it, i posted it below, appreciate the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally you start the symfony internal php server with:
    `php bin/console server:run`
to go on the server you have to put `localhost:8000`in the browser, on a other device in the same network `ipoflocalpc:8000` doesn't work.

to solve this problem and get access to the php server you have to start the server with: `php bin/console server:run 0.0.0.0:80`
then you just have to put in the `ipoflocalpc`and you can get access to the website on every device in the network.

have fun testing on you smartphone :D

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of proxy on your dev computer (nginx or lighthttpd) to forward the http://localhost:8000 to http://your_public_ip:80 (or any other port)